# top_topics Gensim NameError: global name 'np' is not defined

Tags: python, gensim

I am running (from Gensim)

```
top_topics(corpus, num_topics=5, num_words=20)
```

I get the error:

```
for topic in lda.top_topics(corpus=corpus, num_topics=5, num_words=20):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 760, in top_topics
bestn = np.argsort(topic)[::-1][:num_words]
NameError: global name 'np' is not defined
```

I thought this was odd and I can see the file (indeed it has `import numpy` but not `import numpy as np`).

After adding `import numpy as np` and trying to run it again:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 772, in top_topics
    if len(list(ifilter(lambda x: x[0] == id,corpus[document]))) > 0:
```

NameError: global name 'ifilter' is not defined

Which was fixed by changing `from itertools import chain` to `from itertools import chain, ifilter`. The module then works perfectly.

So, I guess my question is whether this was an error specific to my system (is there some kind of 'import all' python trick that doesn't work for me?).

Comment: I think there's something broken in gensim installation. See if you can update it with the latest version.

Comment: I get `Requirement already up-to-date: gensim in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade your numpy, if you are using pip use `pip install --upgrade numpy`

for safety, also try to upgrade you gensim